# Does the phrase "in a way" makes such a difference in a statement?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "in a way" makes such a difference in a statement?

In other words, is there a major difference by saying:

> "In a way, a part of you thinks they should have been together."

and

> "They should have been together."

Comment: Your title does not match the text:  The difference between the two sentences is *In a way, a part of you thinks*, not just *in a way*. Please [edit].

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it doesn’t make a major difference but still makes a difference.

> "They should have been together."

Is definite and expresses no uncertainty in anyway

> "In a way, a part of you thinks they should have been together."

This leaves some doubt and less certainty in the answer. It also adds the fact there are multiple angles and viewpoints in the situation.

For example:

> They looked really cute and got on well with each other. **They should have been together.**

That expresses certainty and is supported by giving two reasons.

Another example:

> They looked really cute but argued a lot. **In a way, a part of you thinks they should have been together.**

Here, there is uncertainty as one reason is positive and the other negative.

**All in all, it does make a slight difference but not major. In some contexts it looks better and makes a bigger difference,**

Comment: Agreed. This is the same way that I understood the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "In a way" changes a sentence that much.

I believe that "In a way" sounds like you are uncertain that they should have been together, but "In a way", you could see how they could end up together.

and

Saying "They should have been together" sounds like you know for a fact or that you are very sure that they should've been together.